# Dynamic input textfield JQuery Datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a jsp. When a link is clicked in JSP, javascript function adds two input text fields with ids and names as fromDate, toDate.

I tried to apply datePicker to fromDate. 
I put an alert before applying and after applying. 
I get both alerts. No java console errors. But datePicker doesnot get applied on fromDate.

I wonder where the problem is. 
I will appreciate if someone can throw light in this regards,

-Indu

### my JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>SB Reports</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<c:import url="SBUserNameDisp.jsp" />
<div class="mid-area">
<h2>Reports</h2>

<table border="5" width="970">
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top" width="100">
<c:import url="DispUserMenu.jsp" />
</td >
<td style="vertical-align: top" width="100">
<p class="subheading">Reports</p>
<a href="#" onclick="viewFeedback()">View Feedbacks</a>
</td>
<td width="770" style="vertical-align: top" id="displayDataCell">  
    <p class="subheading" align="center"><br><br><br><br><br><b>Report Area</b>
 </p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jsFunctions.js"/></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" 
  href="resources/css/datepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/datepicker.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
//$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    $("#fromDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val();
    $("#toDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val();
  });

</script>

</html>
```

---

my .js functions

```
function viewFeedback(){
var displayDataCell = document.getElementById("displayDataCell");
displayDataCell.innerHTML = buildFeedbackSelection();
alert("INDU1");
setDateForDatepicker();
$('.fromDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
alert("INDU2");
} // viewFeedback

function setDateForDatepicker(){
var currentDate = new Date();
var day = currentDate.getDate();
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
if(day < 10)   { day = '0' + day;}; 
if(month < 10) { month = '0' + month;};
var my_date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
document.getElementById("fromDate").value=my_date;
document.getElementById("toDate").value=my_date;
} // setDateForDatePicker

function buildFeedbackSelection(){
var str = "";
var qte = "\"";
var date = "";

str += "<table valign=" + qte + "top" + qte + " border=" + qte + "0"
+ qte + " width=" + qte + "100%" + qte + ">";
str += "<tr>";
str += "<td>";
str += "From Date <input type=" + qte + "text" + qte 
    + " id=" + qte  + "fromDate" + qte 
    + " name=" + qte + "fromDate" + qte
    + " value=" + qte + date + qte 
    + " class=" + qte + "hasDatepicker" + qte + ">";
str += "</td>";
str += "<td>";
str += "To Date <input type=" + qte + "text" + qte 
    + " id=" + qte  + "toDate" + qte 
    + " name=" + qte + "toDate" + qte 
    + " value=" + qte + date + qte 
    + " class=" + qte + "hasDatepicker" + qte + ">";
str += "</td>";
str += "<td>";
str += "<input type=" + qte + "button" + qte + "  class=" + qte
    + "btn-bg" + qte + "  onclick=" + qte + "showFeedback()" + qte
    + "  value=" + qte + "Show" + qte + "> &nbsp;&nbsp";

str += "<input type=" + qte + "button" + qte + "  class=" + qte
    + "btn-bg" + qte + "  onclick=" + qte + "deleteFeedback()"
    + qte + "  value=" + qte + "Delete" + qte + ">";
str += "</td>";
str += "</tr>";
str += "<tr>";
str += "<td colspan=" + qte + "3" + qte + "id=" + qte + "reportArea"
    + qte + ">";
str += "<p align=" + qte + "center" + qte + " class=" + qte
    + "subheading" + qte + ">Feedback Data Here</p>";
str += "</td>";
str += "</tr>";
str += "</table>";

return str;
} // buildFeedbackSelection
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I spot two problems here.

Firstly, this `<script>` tag inside your JSP will run and try to append datepicker to elements before they exist on the page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
        $("#fromDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val();
        $("#toDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val();
    });
</script>
```

That won't work. You have to make sure the elements exist on the page before you try to instantiate the datepicker, so you have to wait until after `viewFeedback()` creates these two inputs with `buildFeedbackSection()`.

Secondly, in the function `viedFeedback()` you are trying to get the element by class instead of by id. You mentioned that these two input fields get created dynamically and have IDs of "fromDate" and "toDate". In jQuery (and CSS) IDs are represented by a hash `#` and classes are represented by a dot `.`. You will have to change the line

```
$('.fromDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```

to

```
$('#fromDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I Changed the jquery tag reference from . --> #  and removed the script from JSP.  But it did not work still.